# Different ways of calling methods in Python, How they work?

Tags: python, class, object

```
class Test():
    def a(self):
        return 6
Test_instance=Test()
print(Test.a(Test_instance))
print(Test_instance.a())
print(Test.a(Test_instance,3))
print(Test_instance.a(3))
```

The code above give me the following result:

```
6
6
TypeError: a() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

If I exclude the line `print(Test.a(Test_instance,3))` I get the same print out. But Isn't `a` a method of both, `Test` class and `Test_instance` object? When I write `Test_instance.a()` I supose I'm giving one argument to the `a()` method of `Test_instance` and when I write `Test.a(Test_instance)` I supose I'm giving two arguments to the `a()` method of `Test`. But the error says that `Test.a(Test_instance,3)` gives 2 arguments. Shouldn't it be 3?

Comment: Instead of describing your class, post your code as a block!

Comment: You have way too much text _describing_ your code without actually giving a simple example of it. Your verbosity in explaining your code could just be wholly replaced with the actual code, and it would better help us understand your problem.

Comment: Sorry, I edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But Isn't ***"a"*** a method of both, ***Test*** object and ***Test_instance*** object?.

It is indeed.

> When I write `Test_instance.a()` I supose im giving one argument to ***"a"*** method of ***Test_instance*** and When I write `Test.a(Test_instance)` I supose Im giving two arguments to ***"a"*** method of ***Test***.

Right. But that applies only to method calls on instances.

> But the error says that `Test.a(Test_instance,3)` gives 2 arguments. Shouldn't be 3?

No. It is 2, as you call the method directly on the class and not via the instance.

Calling a method directly on the class calls it as it is.

Calling a method on the instance, however, prepends the instance as first argument.

The reason for this are the internals.

If I do `instance.X`, `X` is a class member and implements the `__get__()` method (Descriptor protocol), internally `X.__get__()` is called and the result of it is produced for `instance.X`.

And functions implement the descriptor protocol in order to create an instance method object, which is reponsible for prepending the instance as first argument.

So, in your example, you as well can do

```
>>> print(Test_instance.a)
<bound method Test.a of <__main__.Test instance at 0x7f6e232e3690>>
>>> Test.a.__get__(Test_instance, Test)
<bound method Test.a of <__main__.Test instance at 0x7f6e232e3690>>
```

Both these "bound methods" are what I referred to as "instance method object".

Other example for this:

```
class Desc(object):
    def __get__(self, a, b):
        print('Calling __get__(%r, %r, %r)' % (self, a, b))
        return a or b
class Test():
    x = Desc()

>>> Test.x
Calling __get__(<__main__.Desc object at 0x7f6e232e1810>, None, <class __main__.Test at 0x7f6e232ea050>)
<class __main__.Test at 0x7f6e232ea050>
>>> inst = Test()
>>> inst.x
Calling __get__(<__main__.Desc object at 0x7f6e232e1810>, <__main__.Test instance at 0x7f6e232e3c80>, <class __main__.Test at 0x7f6e232ea050>)
<__main__.Test instance at 0x7f6e232e3c80>
```

What happens here?

`Test.x` takes the `x` member of `Test` and calls its `.__get__(x, None, Test)`. This method returns `b` (which is set to `Test`), as the `a` parameter is `None`.

`inst.x` takes the `x` member of `Test` and calls its `.__get__(x, inst, Test)`. This in turn returns `a`.

In a similar way, methods are set up to work.

Properties as well use the same mechanism, BTW.

If you use the `@classmethod` and `@staticmethod` decorators, they wrap the functions into some wrapping objects which have a slightly different `.__get__()` behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `instance.a()`, `instance` is impliciltly passed as the first argument. When you do `instance.a(3)`, you give two arguments (the implicit first `instance`, and the explicit `3`), which your function cannot handle.

When you do `Test.a()`, `Test` is not passed as an implicit first argument because `a` is not defined as a class method.
If you do

```
class Test():
    @classmethod
    def a(self):
        return 6
```

and then try `Test.a(123)` would give you the error `a() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

Or `Test.a(Test_instance,3)`, you'll get the error you expect.

Comment: When we define a instance method inside Test, we create a method for instances of Test and for the Test object itself right?

Comment: Partially correct. You _could_ access the instance function via the class like `Test.a(123)`, but then you're deliberately using it in an unintended way. Decorating the function with `@classmethod` or `@sstaticmethod` tells python how you want the first argument to work (or not). Some more info [here](https://realpython.com/instance-class-and-static-methods-demystified/) and [here](https://stackabuse.com/pythons-classmethod-and-staticmethod-explained/)